# Can't debug in qt-creator, cdb crashes 0xC0000135

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010, qt-creator, windbg

When I run debug in debug mode in Qt-Creator it simply says

> Debugging started. Debugging finished.

The debug output is huge but here's the important part:

```
dNOTE: ENGINE RUN AND INFERIOR RUN OK
sRunning.
dState changed from EngineRunRequested(7) to InferiorRunOk(11) [master]
 ModLoad: 00000000`76e40000 00000000`76f5f000   WOW64_IMAGE_SECTION
 ModLoad: 00000000`74fb0000 00000000`750c0000   WOW64_IMAGE_SECTION
 ModLoad: 00000000`76e40000 00000000`76f5f000   NOT_AN_IMAGE
 ModLoad: 00000000`76f60000 00000000`7705a000   NOT_AN_IMAGE
 ModLoad: 00000000`74fb0000 00000000`750c0000   C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`758d0000 00000000`75917000   C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`647e0000 00000000`64f4c000   C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010_opengl\bin\Qt5Widgetsd.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`755f0000 00000000`75680000   C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`74e70000 00000000`74f70000   C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75280000 00000000`75320000   C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75930000 00000000`759dc000   C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`76e20000 00000000`76e39000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75320000 00000000`75410000   C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`74c90000 00000000`74cf0000   C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`74c80000 00000000`74c8c000   C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`758b0000 00000000`758ba000   C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`74dd0000 00000000`74e6d000   C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75e70000 00000000`76aba000   C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`750c0000 00000000`75117000   C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`0f7b0000 00000000`0fd12000   C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010_opengl\bin\Qt5Guid.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`50e70000 00000000`50f38000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OPENGL32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`53480000 00000000`534a2000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\GLU32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`50b10000 00000000`50bf7000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DDRAW.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`53cb0000 00000000`53cb6000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DCIMAN32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`76bf0000 00000000`76d8d000   C:\Windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`74d60000 00000000`74d87000   C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75de0000 00000000`75e6f000   C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75410000 00000000`7556c000   C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`74d90000 00000000`74da2000   C:\Windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`6dc70000 00000000`6dc83000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`66ac0000 00000000`67197000   C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010_opengl\bin\Qt5Cored.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`74f70000 00000000`74fa5000   C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`74db0000 00000000`74db6000   C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`4a900000 00000000`4aa49000   C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010_opengl\bin\icuin49.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`00340000 00000000`00447000   C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010_opengl\bin\icuuc49.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`00760000 00000000`01882000   C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010_opengl\bin\icudt49.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`61ff0000 00000000`620af000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCR100.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`00510000 00000000`00579000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCP100.dll
sProcess exited (3221225781)
eERROR: Process crashed
eERROR: CDB crashed
dNOTE: ENGINE SPONTANEOUS SHUTDOWN
dState changed BY FORCE from InferiorRunOk(11) to EngineShutdownOk(22) [master]
dState changed from EngineShutdownOk(22) to DebuggerFinished(23) [master]
dQUEUE: FINISH DEBUGGER
dNOTE: FINISH DEBUGGER
dHANDLE RUNCONTROL FINISHED
sDebugger finished.
```

I am using Windows 7, QT-5.02 compiled for OpenGL, MSVC2010, QT-Creator 2.7.0, Windows SDK 7.1, VS2010. The problem exists regardless of which version of the VC++ Compiler I use (9.0 vs 10.0) .

I have already tried reinstalling Windows SDK, all the VC++ redistributables, QT, and QT-Creator.

The problem persists no matter what project I use, even a simple hello world with no QT calls.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

1. Can you run your application without the debugger - in other words, does it always crash?
2. Did you check all of your dependencies for your application?  ([dependency walker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker) & [redistributables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

I'm asking because there's a similar [post with your error code](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/42042-QtCreator-falls-on-start-project) that indicates your issue may be dealing with missing DLLs not found in the directory or %PATH%.

I just setup my [CDB in windows 7](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.7/creator-debugger-engines.html) from scratch and had no problems.

Comment: The app works fine in release mode. And when I run dependency walker I get the following files as missing: API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL

However, these files are also missing in the release version which runs fine.

Comment: Also, dependency walker doesn't show it,but launching the app from  explorer says that I'm missing MSVCP100d.dll, which I do have both versions of located in system32 (although they are lowercase, would that matter?)

Comment: Also, I've set up the symbol server location and I'm doing all of the debugging locally.

Comment: case for (files) doesn't matter on windows.  dependency walker can tend to show a few missing dlls - which is explained in another thread somewhere on this site.  the MSVCP100d.dll error is just cause you're not running in the MSVC environment - which is consistent with why the release mode works.  can you run the app in debug mode from QtCreator (different than running under the debugger)?

Comment: Running from qt-creator in debug mode but without the debugger (the plain green arrow) I get "THe program has unexpectedly finished." and an exit code of -1073741515. Running with the debugger gives the error above. I'm testing on an empty program that simply returns 0.

Comment: Any chance you are you mixing up x86 with x64?  Meaning, the Qt libraries are one flavor and your MSVC install is another?

Comment: The debugger, qt, and my redistributables are all x86.

Comment: Is there any hard reset type uninstall I could do that might fix this or am I stuck just debugging on another machine?

Comment: I tend to believe it's a configuration or environment issue (env variables or DLLs which is at the top of my list).  So is your application as simple as int main(int argc, char** argv) { return 0; }  ???  we could take this off into a chat instead

Comment: Hi @user2525598, were u able to solve this? i'm facing an identical issue.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding ICU to the path (which for me was `\dev\icu4c-51_2-Win64-msvc10\icu\bin64`).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same log and same error. I resolved it by copying the 2 files from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugCRT to the path where the exe can access(in my scenario, I'm compiling 32bit app on 64bit machine, and I copied to the folder where QCore5d.dll is).